# Monitoring stats published on our site, should we?

Tags: centos, security, monitoring, centos7, zabbix

So this could also fit @[InformationSecurity](https://security.stackexchange.com/) as some concerns are related to security. We are building the website for our gameserver hosting project and we would like to be as transparent as possible with our customers. One of the ways of doing this would be by sharing real time graphs of resources such as RAM and bandwith usage, and CPU load on the site.

- **Security related question:** Would it be risky sharing this kind of information?

We are currently monitoring all of our resources with [Zabbix](http://www.zabbix.com/) which allows user access as *guest* to the platform and that user can be, in some way, chrooted so he can not see more than we want to, he can not change anything and so on. This way (loging into zabbix panel and finding where the screens are) seems a bit unhealthy for the user experience in my opinion so having a screen showing on our site would be much better.

- **Server related question:** Does Zabbix supports this? (so far I couldn't find any info even talking about it)

Comment: You're stating 'real-time' as a requirement, but is it really?AFAIK, Zabbix can resolve down to the 1-minute interval, so at the most you would have a 1+ minute lag. As far as the security portion of the question: I'd be quite leery of allowing anyone access to my monitoring server. The main risk of sharing this type of information is that it allows an attacker to gain insight into your network topology and system setup. Aggregation and anonymization of your statistics would be a good thing in this instance.

Comment: @ThomasN by "real time" I meant refreshed every x seconds (60 in this case). Appart from that, I agree, letting someone into your system, even if "jailed", is something you want to avoid and that's why I'm looking for a different solution for showing the graphs as if they just were another element on the site.

Comment: It would let an attacker know exactly the impact their DDoS is having on your site. I don't like this idea.

Comment: I can see minimal upsides and significant security downsides. Perhaps you should just say "servers are actively monitored to ensure sufficient resources are available", and perhaps you could create a static image which shows a typical 24 hour period. The answer by Richlv below makes the most sense, but I'm not even sure I'd bother with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concentrating on the Zabbix side - I'd suggest not to expose Zabbix interface to the internet. As for sharing a few select graphs, there is no built-in solution in Zabbix, but a common approach is to wget graph images (you can specify timeframe and width among other parameters) which are just PNGs - then place those anywhere you would like to.

Comment: This answer + the comments made it clear, will just `wget` the graphs as an static png and will update ever 24 hours or so, thanks.

Comment: That seems very reasonable, if that helps as an encouragement :)